# Matlab programming row echelon form of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here I wrote a code in matlab to reduce a matrix to row echelon form

```
function A = myrref(A)

[m,n]=size(A);

for j=1:m

    A(j,:) = A(j,:)/A(j,j);

    for i = 1:n
        if j < i
        A(i,:)= A(i,:)- A(j,:)*A(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

I have a problem though, this code does not seem to work for non square matrices. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the row index and must be less than or equal to `m`, not `n`; `j` should not exceed the number of columns:

```
for j=1:min(m,n)
A(j,:) = A(j,:)/A(j,j);
    for i = j+1:m
        A(i,:)= A(i,:)- A(j,:)*A(i,j);
    end
end
```

Also note that this code will not work when `A(j,j)` is equal to `0`